# Surjective homomorphisms on decomposition and inertia groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Assume that $L/\mathbb{Q}$ and $K/\mathbb{Q}$ are Galois extensions with $K \subset L$.
Let $p$ be a prime of $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathfrak p$ be a prime of $K$ lying over $p$, and $P$ be a prime of $L$ lying over $\mathfrak p$.
$\renewcommand{\Gal}{\mathrm{Gal}}$

Let $$I(P/p) \trianglelefteq D(P/p) ≤ \Gal(L/\Bbb Q)$$ be respectively the decomposition and inertia groups of the prime $P$ over $p$. Similarly for $I(\mathfrak p/p) \trianglelefteq D(\mathfrak p/p) ≤ \Gal(K/\Bbb Q)$.

**My questions are:**

> 1. Why is the morphism
>      $$f : D(P/p) \to D(\mathfrak p/p) \qquad f(\sigma) = \sigma\vert_K$$
>      surjective?
> 2. Why is the morphism
>      $$g : I(P/p) \to I(\mathfrak p/p) \qquad g(\sigma) = \sigma\vert_K$$
>      surjective?

I know that
the restriction map $r:\Gal(L/\mathbb{Q}) \to \Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is surjective, and that $f,g$ are well-defined. I also know that
$$r' : \dfrac{D(P/p)}{I(P/p)} \to \dfrac{D(\mathfrak p/p)}{I(\mathfrak p/p)}$$ is surjective.

The order of $D(P/p)$ is
$$e(P/p)f(P/p) =
e(P/\mathfrak p) e(\mathfrak p/p)
f(P/\mathfrak p) f(\mathfrak p/p)
 \geq 
e(\mathfrak p/p)f(\mathfrak p/p) = |D(\mathfrak p/p)|$$
so this is a necessary condition for surjectivity.

In other words (for 1.), I would like to show that
if $\sigma(\mathfrak p) = \mathfrak p$ then
$\sigma(P)=P$, where $\mathfrak p = P \cap K$ and $\sigma \in \Gal(L/\Bbb Q)$.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89855/surjectivity-of-group-homomorphisms/) is a related question.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: $e(P/p),f(P/p)$ are the ramification index and intertia degree, not the same as $f(\sigma) = \sigma_K$

Comment: And since $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois and $\mathbb{Q} \subset K \subset L$ then $L/K$ is a Galois extension

Comment: @user1952009 : what do you mean by "not the same as $f(σ)=σ_K$"? And yes, $L/K$ is Galois, so that $D(P/\mathfrak p)$ makes sense, for instance.

Comment: it is not the same $f$

Comment: Ah ok… but I think the context is clear. Even if my homomorphism is called $f$, the notation $f(P/p)$ is only for inertia index.

Comment: This is actually proved in Ribenboim, _Classical Theory of Algebraic Numbers_, p. 263 (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtvUa.jpg)).

Comment: Yes of course. The subject is not so easy so it is better to state everything as clearly and simple as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that $ \sigma(\mathfrak p) = \mathfrak p $ implies $ \sigma(P) = P $, for obvious reasons. (Try this on a concrete example.)

Note that the kernel of the map $ D(P/p) \to D(\mathfrak p/p) $ given by restriction to $ K $ is exactly $ \textrm{Gal}(L/K) \cap D(P/p) = D(P/\mathfrak p) $. Thus, there is an embedding $ D(P/p)/D(P/\mathfrak p) \to D(\mathfrak p/p) $. However, by multiplicativity of ramification index and inertia degree, these groups have equal order, thus the injection must actually be an isomorphism, i.e the initial map must be surjective. I leave (2) as an exercise, the proof idea is similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So actually, we don't even need to use directly the surjectivity of the restriction morphism $\Gal(L/\Bbb Q) \to \Gal(K/\Bbb Q)$ ?

Comment: Notice that you can use `\Gal` here (I defined a renewcommand).

Comment: The surjectivity of the restriction morphism can be derived in the same way in the finite case if one does not want to use isomorphism extension - indeed, restriction gives an embedding $ \Gal(L/\mathbf Q) / \Gal(L/K) \to \textrm{Gal}(K/\mathbf Q) $, which must be surjective by order considerations. Thus, while we are not using the result directly, we are still using the "spirit" of it, in a sense.